# Google Oauth2.0 Dynamic URL for every domain

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm currently working on a multidomain website that should have google Oauth2.0 authentication. I want to get it to work on the back-end. For every individual domain, I need a redirect URL that contains the right domain. But I can't seem to parse a custom feedback URL to the google OAuth strategy. I know google does not allow dynamic urls for security reasons. But I just want "https://<domain>/googleAuthRedirect?code=<token>".

I plan on parsing the domain in the request URL "https://universalBackend/oauth/v2/loginGoogle/<domain>"

I think it should be possible by creating a custom strategy object per request with the right domain in the redirect URL. But I can't seem to figure out how to put that in code.

Thanks in advance.

My current passport.js conf

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: '',
        clientSecret: '',
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

        // Todo Check if registered in xfw, if not register, if registered then log in
        console.log('Access', profile.id);
        done();

    })
);
```

My current authRouter.ts

```
oAuthRouter.get('/loginGoogle', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile']
}));

oAuthRouter.get('/googleRedirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.json(req.user)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. This way I can change the callback URL dynamically based on request.

```
oAuthRouter.get('/loginGoogle', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    passport._strategies.google._callbackURL = 'http://localhost:8081/api/OauthV2/googleRedirect';

    // @ts-ignore
    console.log(passport._strategies.google._callbackURL)

    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] })(req, res, next);
});
```